# Freemarker: Not sure HOW to Give Numerical Sequence to a list of step objects

Tags: itext, reporting, freemarker

I need to give numerical sequence to below steps and child-steps in a fixed hierarchy but I can't figure out how exactly it can be done. I have tried giving the numerical sequence to a series of steps and child steps using  tags earlier but that did not work and was giving PDF report with repetitive numerical hierarchy.

```
<#macro recursive step>
<div class="mainStep">
    <#if step.text?has_content>

        <p>
            ${step.text} 
        </p>

    </#if>
</div>

<#if step.stepDocContentList?has_content>

    <#list step.stepDocContentList as content>
        <#if content.picturePath?has_content>
            <div id="${content.picturePath}">
                <figure>
                    <img class="realSizePicture" src="${content.picturePath}">
            </div>
            <#if content.title?has_content>
                <figcaption> ${content.title} </figcaption>
            </#if>
            </figure>
        </#if>
    </#list>

</#if>
<div class="childSteps">
    <#list step.subSteps as childSteps>
        <@recursive childSteps />
    </#list>
</div>
```

</#macro>

Comment: i think using assign directive we can figure out some way but then again how exactly do we do that, I am unable to figure out a way. If anyone out there has some knowledge to share please do i am kind of stuck and there seems no way forward.

Comment: This is an algorithm question, not really a FreeMarker question. But anyway, the idea is that your macro (which should be rather called `showStepRecursively`) needs two parameters. 1st is the `step` to show, and 2nd is the number of that step. e.g. `"3.11"`. So now in the macro can know that the first child steps will `"3.11.1"`, `"3.11.2"`. etc. And when you call yourself recursively again, you can pass `"3.11.1"` etc. as the 2nd parameter. For the sake of the top level call, the 2nd parameter should have default value `""`.

Comment: @ddekany yeah I found the parameter for step number and was able to show the numerical hierarchy in the reports. thanks for the inputs mate.